# Как пользоваться find_library в cmake?

Tags: c, cmake, библиотеки

Я не могу понять, как найти в системе собственную скомпилированную статическую библиотеку. Что нужно прописать в find_library, чтоб найти библиотеку, располагающуюся по пути `/home/anton/dev/testtresh/untitled2/cmake-build-debug/libmath.a`?

Comment: а эта библиотека собирается своим CMakeLists.txt файлом или это просто скомпилированная библиотека и на самом деле Вам нужно просто ее подлинковать, а find_library - просто попался под руку?

Comment: @KoVadim Она уже скомпилирована в .а файл

Comment: В /home/anton/dev/testtresh/untitled2/inc лежат h файлы, а по пути выше сма библиотека

Comment: @KoVadim, по стуи да, попался

Comment: тогда либо пишите обвязку, либо просто укажите где лежат хедеры и бинарники и оно  подтянется. То есть, include_directories для хедера, target_link_libraries для a файла